# How to program dice rolls for two players

Tags: java, processing, dice

(Processing) The code isn't returning what I want it to. Basically, there are two players, and each player takes turn rolling a die. The values should be stored in the variable "p1diceroll" and "p2diceroll" respectively. It will compare the two values, and release who will be going first based on who rolled higher.

```
void setup(){
    size (100,100);
    background(200,200,200); 
    println("press l to roll the die!");
}

void draw() {
      if(keyPressed)
          keyPressed();
      noLoop();
}

void keyPressed(){
    int p1diceroll=0;
    int p2diceroll=0;

    if (key == 'l') {
        double rand1 = Math.random();
        double rand2 = rand1*6;
        double rand3 = rand2 +1;
        p1diceroll = (int)rand3;

        println("You rolled a " + p1diceroll + "!"); 
        println("player 1! press 'a' to roll");
    }

    if (key == 'a') {
        double rand11 = Math.random();
        double rand22 = rand11*6;
        double rand33 = rand22 +1;
        p2diceroll = (int)rand33;

        println("You rolled a " + p2diceroll + "!");


        if (p2diceroll>p1diceroll) {
            System.out.println("player 2  rolled higher!. They go first. "); 
        } else if (p2diceroll==p1diceroll) {
            System.out.println("It's a tie! player 1 goes first by default." ); 
        } else {
          println("player 1 rolled higher! They go first.");
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be either, "player 2  rolled higher!. They go first.", "It's a tie! player 1 goes first by default.", or "player 1 rolled higher. They go first."

Comment: I will answer, give me a second

Comment: We need to see the rest of your code. From just this I cannot tell if you're making small mistakes or if you are completely lost on how programming works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addition to A.A's answer here are few Processing options:

1. [`random()`](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html) (e.g. `println((int)random(1,7));` (casting to `int` is equivalent to `println(floor(random(1,7)));` which would drop the floating point number to a floored into between 1-6.
2. [`randomGaussian()`](https://processing.org/reference/randomGaussian_.html) might be fun to play with the [distribution is closer to a dice roll](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482813/is-rolling-a-dice-a-gauss-distribution)
3. [`noise()`](https://processing.org/reference/noise_.html) will give you a lot of options, especially in tandem with [`noiseSeed()`](https://processing.org/reference/noiseSeed_.html) and [`noiseDetail()`](https://processing.org/reference/noiseDetail_.html)

I've also noticed the diceroll values per player are reset each time the key is pressed.
I'm not 100% sure that is what you intended as one of the two values will always be 0.

Here's a tweaked version of your code using `random()` and debug text:

```
int p1diceroll=0;
int p2diceroll=0;

String result = "";

void setup(){
    size (120,120);
    background(200,200,200); 
    println("press l to roll the die!");
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  text("press 'l' for p1"
      +"\npress 'a' for p2"
      +"\n\np1diceroll: " + p1diceroll
      +"\np2diceroll: " + p2diceroll
      +"\n\n"+result,5,15);
}

void keyPressed(){
    if (key == 'l') {
        p1diceroll = (int)random(1,7);

        println("You(p1) rolled a " + p1diceroll + "!"); 
        println("player 2! press 'a' to roll");
    }

    if (key == 'a') {
        p2diceroll = (int)random(1,7);

        println("You(p2) rolled a " + p2diceroll + "!");

        if (p2diceroll > p1diceroll) {
          println("player 2  rolled higher(" + p2diceroll + " > " + p1diceroll + ")!. They go first. ");
          result = "player 2\ngoes first";
        } else if (p2diceroll == p1diceroll) {
          println("It's a tie! player 1 goes first by default." );
          result = "tie! player 1\ngoes first";
        } else {
          println("player 1 rolled higher(" + p1diceroll + " > " + p2diceroll + ")! They go first.");
          result = "player 1\ngoes first";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be:

```
import java.util.Random;

Random rand = new Random();


if (key == 'l'){
    // Obtain a number between [0 - 5].
    int p1diceroll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    println("You rolled a " + p1diceroll + "!"); 
    println("player 2! press 'a' to roll");
  }
 if (key == 'a'){

   // Obtain a number between [0 - 5].
   int p2diceroll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
```

Then you can just compare it like you did after.

Please note, that the number in brackets is an intervall between [0-6) including 0 and excluding 6 we add +1 after to get 1-6

You are also saying "player1 press a to roll" eventhough it is player2 turn. I adjusted that in the given code above.

Comment: @JasmineLiao If that worked out for you, please mark the answer as solved, so other people can see the solution too. Thank you :)